# What is the difference between Carborundum Glass and Borosilicate Glass and which has better adhesion properties?

Tags: creality-ender-3, adhesion, bed, glass-bed

I'm choosing a new bed for the Creality Ender 3 V2. It's unclear if the Creality Ender 3 V2 came originally with a Carborundum Glass bed or a Borosilicate Glass bed. What is the actual difference between Carborundum Glass and Borosilicate Glass and which has better 3D printer bed properties such as adhesion?

(I'm not interested in personal preference or opinion, which seem to be involved in most available information regarding printer bed choice.)